# Detecting terminal width over Telnet

Tags: c, sockets, terminal, network-programming, telnet

I am writing a WarGames server (emulating the W.O.P.R. from the movie) that listens for connections over telnet, in C.

When the main character dials into the W.O.P.R. for the first time, it prints two empty lines, filled with spaces before the login prompt. I want to emulate this in my server.

My question is this: How do I find the terminal width over telnet so I know how many spaces to print?

EDIT: I want to try to avoid using any external libraries. This is a learning project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The telnet protocol does have some stuff for that, but as with anything in C it'll take some reading for the full details: http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1073.txt

> ```
>   IAC SB NAWS <16-bit value> <16-bit value> IAC SE
>   Sent by the Telnet client to inform the Telnet server of the window width and height.
> ```